# which software can produce this 3d file?

Tags: 3d

Now i have a file named file.3d ,the contents of the file are similar with below:

> **T**  model/file.bmp
>
> **M**
>
> 1 1.454459 -4.069280 16.820227 0.921623 -0.163685 -0.351877 0.338465
>   0.550959 1 1.732314 -3.945513 17.490400 0.966073 -0.145701 0.213248 0.328628 0.577800 1 1.171872 -4.761898 17.010565 0.842542 -0.533085 -0.077096 0.357091 0.562627
>
> 1 1.732314 -3.945513 17.490400 0.966073 -0.145701 0.213248 0.328628
>   0.577800 1 0.647007 -5.256052 17.856688 0.765348 -0.532969 0.360814 0.350134 0.590982 1 1.171872 -4.761898 17.010565 0.842542 -0.533085 -0.077096 0.357091 0.562627
>
> **M**
>
> **S**
>
> 0 -1
>
> 1 0
>
> 2 0
>
> 3 0
>
> 4 2
>
> 5 3
>
> 6 4
>
> 7 5
>
> 8 0
>
> 9 8
>
> 10 8
>
> 11 9
>
> 12 10
>
> 13 11
>
> 14 12
>
> 15 13
>
> 16 14
>
> 17 15
>
> 18 16
>
> 19 8
>
> 20 19
>
> 21 20
>
> 22 21
>
> 23 22
>
> 24 23
>
> 25 24
>
> **S**
>
> **J**
>
> 0 0.039382 0.000004 11.387473 1.570796 0.000000 0.000000 1 -0.050000
>   5.900000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 2 2.950000 -0.250000 -0.000000 -2.164269 1.547812 -3.141593 3 -2.850000 -0.250000 -0.000000 2.148354 1.546611 0.000000 4 0.000000 0.000000 3.890210 -0.528631 0.568091 -3.141593 5 -0.000000 -0.000000 3.830288 0.516909 0.556028 -3.141593
>
> **J**

I found that there are four section, include T, M, S and J.

I want to kown that which software can produce these datas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write your own parser for 3d point in space and display them in the screen.

I can't see any pattern in the text file so i can't help you.